# Docker build error while running nx build

Tags: angular, docker, nomachine-nx

I have an angular ssr application that I build into an image. I faced a really strange situation. My docker build always failing when i run the nx build command,exit code 1.
The most fustrating thing that on docker desktop->builds-> error shows red text with some warnings and this line:

> NX   Successfully ran target build for project bringaznimentem-fe

I tried that to comment out the build command and set the entrypoint to get a runnable image. After i run a container with this image can sucessfully execute the nx build command inside the container, so really dont have any idea what's the problem with that.
Docker file:

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.17 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/

RUN npm install
# RUN npm i -g @angular/cli
RUN npm install -g @nrwl/cli
RUN npm install --global nx@latest

COPY ./ /app/
ARG configuration=production
RUN nx build # this line is failing
RUN nx run my-project:server

FROM node:16-alpine3.17 AS ssr-server
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/ /app/dist/
COPY ./package.json /app/package.json

EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["node", "./dist/my-project/server/main.js"]
```

Node: 18.12.1
Package Manager: npm 9.6.6
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 15.1.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server
... router

```
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1501.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.1.6
@angular-devkit/core            15.1.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.10
@angular/cdk                    15.2.5
@angular/cli                    15.2.10
@angular/google-maps            14.2.7
@nguniversal/builders           15.1.0
@nguniversal/express-engine     15.1.0
@schematics/angular             15.2.10
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.9.5

  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^14.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.5",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^15.1.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.13",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "helmet": "^7.1.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-sharebuttons": "^12.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "snazzy-info-window": "^1.1.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.1.6",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^15.1.6",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^15.1.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.1.5",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^15.1.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "15.9.2",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "15.9.2",
    "@schematics/angular": "^15.1.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "nx": "15.9.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5"
  }
```

Comment: can you check that your Dockerfile is correctly configured to build your Angular SSR application. Ensure that all the necessary dependencies and build commands are included in the Dockerfile. also check that the dockerfile is located in the correct directory and that it references the correct files and directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is set version for nx in the docker file.

```
RUN npm install -g @nrwl/cli@15.9.7
RUN npm i nx@17.0.0
```

It would have been great if it had shown a proper error message....